# Always getting the last value from row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying get a variable from a php file to another within a "while", but heres my problem:

I have a shop page where I get an 'id' depending on what button you click, then the button takes you to another page (buy.php) where I need this item id to get the correct item from db(sorry for my sh** explanation).

item php:

```
$conn = new mysqli($web_host, $web_user, $web_pw, $web_tbl);
    $sql = "SELECT id, vnum, name, imagine, pret, descriere FROM itemshop_items";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_name']);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $id = $row['id'];
        echo "<tr><div class='is_item'";
        echo "<td><font color='red'>". $row['name'] ."</font></p>";
        echo "<div class='border_img_is'><img src='img/item/". $row['imagine'] ."' width='32px' height='64px' alt='espada'></img></div></p>";
        echo "<div class='preco'>Preço: " . $row['pret'] . "MD's</div>";
        echo "<textarea readonly type='text' id='texto' cols='40' rows='5' name='texto' >".$row['descriere']."</textarea>";
        echo "<a class='comprar_btn' href='index.php?s=buy&id=".$id."'>comprar</a>";
        echo "</tr></div>";
        $preco = $row['pret'];
        $vnum = $row['vnum'];
    }
```

buy.php:

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT vnum, pret, attrtype0, attrvalue0, attrtype1, attrvalue1, attrtype2, attrvalue2, attrtype3, attrvalue3, attrtype4, attrvalue4, attrtype5, attrvalue5, attrtype6, attrvalue6, socket0, socket1, socket2 FROM player.itemshop_items WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==1) {
    $conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass);
    mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("no database by that name");
    $mdsquery = mysql_query("SELECT coins FROM account.account WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id'])."' LIMIT 1");
    $mds = mysql_fetch_object($mdsquery);
    //verificar se user tem mds suficientes, dar return das coins em vez de obj
    if($mds->coins>=$preco){
        //remover coins do user como preco do item
        $nCoins = $mds->coins-$preco;
        $tirar = mysql_query("UPDATE account.account SET coins='".mysql_real_escape_string($nCoins)."' WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id'])."' LIMIT 1");
        //coins removidas, vamos inserir item na conta
        //inserir o item na conta em MALL
        $inserir = mysql_query("INSERT INTO player.item_award (pid,login,vnum,count, given_time, item_id, why, mall) VALUES
         ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_name'])."','".$vnum."','1','0000-00-00 00:00:00', '".$vnum."', 'idk', '1')");
        //get local time
        $datetime = $_POST['date'] . ' ' . $_POST['time'];
        $datetime = mysql_real_escape_string($datetime);
        $datetime = strtotime($datetime);
        $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$datetime);
        //inserir dados da compra nos logs
        $inserir_logs =  mysql_query("INSERT INTO player.itemshop_logs (account,item,id_item,data) VALUES
         ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id'])."','".$vnum."','".$id."','".$datetime."')");
        echo "<div class='top_text'><center><font color='green'>Compraste o item com sucesso! </p></font></center></div>";
    }else{
        echo "<div class='top_text'><center><font color='red'>Não tens moedas suficientes!</font></center></div>";
    }
```

heres my item table:

[image]

result talbe:
[image]

as you can see the "vnum" on this table should be 19 or 189 depending on the button, but it returns always 39!! (the last one on the item)

Comment: why do you use `new mysqli()` in the first file, but `mysql_query()` in the second?

Comment: you show code for `buy.php`, but your link is `href='index.php?s=buy&id=".$id."'`?

Comment: yes, every file is in a related directory, and i use the $id to select the wanted item

Comment: where are you setting `$_SESSION['user_id']`. it looks like you are setting it to the last `id` in your loop, so that is the `id` that is used.

Comment: I'm getting the user_id and user_name from the login page, this doesn't matter because the id and user are working, the problem is that no matter the item I click to buy it always gets me the same(39, the last one)

Comment: so where is you `$vnum = $_GET['id'];` as your link is `href='index.php?s=buy&id=".$id."'`, but I don't see a `$_GET['id']` anywhere in your code. It looks like you are just using `$vnum = $row['vnum'];` which sets `$vnum` to the last in the loop, and not to your posted `id`.

Comment: how can I solve this? also, I'm getting $vnum from the itemshop.php

Comment: I don't know how to solve this, as I am still confused why your link is for `index.php`, but you show the to `buy.php`. last time I checked, `index`!=`buy`. Also, in your `buy.php` code you are using `$_POST['date']`/`'$_POST['time']` so obviously you are getting to `buy.php` from a form, not a link.

Comment: I need the index, its how my page is working(design wise). yes Im getting to buy.php from a link with the id of the item that I want, thats the idea

Comment: So have you tried `$vnum = $_GET['id'];` in `buy.php` since your link is `href='index.php?s=buy&id=".$id."'`

Comment: yes but the id returns 1 2 or 3 , I want it to return the vnum of row with correspondent id

Comment: ok, so I tried this (that should be working) and nope... 

http://i.imgur.com/xsH972j.png

http://i.imgur.com/RKh2XKp.png

Comment: You need to use `vnum` in your link - `echo "<a class='comprar_btn' href='index.php?s=buy&id=".$row['vnum']."'>comprar</a>";`, and then `$vnum = $_GET['id'];` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring vnum multiple times in item.php file and always will keep the last one in this case `39`

This is the Query I am talking about

`SELECT id, vnum, name, imagine, pret, descriere FROM itemshop_items`

Comment: use limit 1 in which one?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo, I think you have to check the SQL query I am talking about. You are declaring as I saidw in my answer, multiple time vnum, and it will keep the last one. If you LIMIT 1 your query it will always return 19. However, I don't think that is what you want. Please review the SQL query

Comment: that only limits the items displayed*